# GNU make pattern rules with different file base names

Tags: gnu-make, rules

I have a data processing job that I would like to automate with Make. Hundreds of files need to be processed, in several steps. 
Unfortunately, the base name will change for at least one of the steps, but it would be easy to write these dependencies into a separate file that then is included.

However, I'd like to avoid also writing the build instructions (which are quite complicated) for all these files separately.

I envisage something along these lines:

```
# automatically generated rules, included into make file
dir1/test.bb: dir2/test_other_name.aa
# (many more rules like the above, linking xxx.bb to yyy.aa)

# pattern rule
%.bb: %.aa
       # build step using $@ $>
```

What I would like is the pattern rule to provide the rules, and the explicit rule defining the dependencies. Can something like this be achieved?

Comment: A more concrete example would greatly clarify what is being asked here, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *make*'s noddy patterns don't cut the mustard,
just write out the rules explicitly.
(This has the happy side effect of not using pattern rules.)

Let's say you have a function `src-to-target` which will generate the target filename (i.e., `$(call src-to-target,dir2/test_other_name.aa)` expands to `dir1/test.bb`.

Also, you have a list of sources in `${srcs}`, and `${recipe}` is a list of shell commands using `$@`, `$<` etc.

```
define src-to-target = ... # $1:source

define recipe =
  echo Building $@ from $<
  ⋮
endef

define generate-rule = # $1:source
target := $(call src-to-taget,$1)
targets += $${target}
$${target}: $1 ; $${recipe}
endef

$(foreach _,${srcs},$(eval $(call generate-rule,$_)))

.PHONY: all
all: ${targets} ; : $@ Success
```

The `$(foreach ...)` does all the work here.

So, looking at that in painful detail,

- First expand `${srcs}`
- Set `$_` to the first in the list (`dir2/test_other_name.aa` say)
- Expand `$(call generate-rule,$_)`

  - Expand `$(call generate-rule,dir2/test_other_name.aa)`

    - `$1` is set to `dir2/test_other_name.aa`, and the expansion of `$(generate-rule)` follows, leading to this block of text

      `target := dir1/test.bb`
      `targets += ${target}`
      `${target}: dir2/test_other_name.aa ; ${recipe}`
- As a side effect, `$(eval)` swallows the above text. The expansion of the `$(eval)` though is empty.
- `$_` is set to the next source file.
- Wash, lather, rinse, repeat

Once the `$(foreach)` is complete,
`${targets}` contains the complete list of targets.

Parallel safe too.
What's not to like?